# ReadFile and WriteFile with Overlapped IO result if not ERROR_IO_PENDING?

Tags: windows, winapi, storage

The docs for FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED on `WriteFile()` say you must provide OVERLAP and recommend NULL for `lpNumberOfBytesWritten` because value is misleading.   However docs for `GetOverlappedResult()` say to only call if `WriteFile()` returned FALSE with ERROR_IO_PENDING.   So that leaves the case where `ReadFile()` / `WriteFile()` complete in the API call itself.  How are you supposed to get the number of bytes read/written?  Do you presume it's the number requested?   But `WriteFile()` says "When writing to a non-blocking, byte-mode pipe handle with insufficient buffer space, WriteFile returns TRUE with * lpNumberOfBytesWritten < nNumberOfBytesToWrite".

TIA!!

Comment: you can call `GetOverlappedResult` also when I/O request (read/write) return true. msdn wrong as usual. anyway, if request not fail just with error - number of bytes will be in `OVERLAPPED.InternalHigh`. *The lpNumberOfBytesWritten parameter should be set to NULL* - this is also absolute wrong. you can pass not 0 here and use it value if I/O return true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If *hFile* was opened with `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` The
>   *`lpNumberOfBytesWritten`* parameter should be set to *NULL*.

this is not true (mistake or lie). the *lpNumberOfBytesWritten* **can** be set to *NULL*, but **not should**. if I/O request complete synchronous with success in *`*lpNumberOfBytesWritten`* will be valid number of bytes.

note also that `lpNumberOfBytes` **must not** point to location which will be valid until operation is complete (like *`lpOverlapped`*) - it can point to local variable in function for example and you can exit from function before I/O is complete - and this is will be ok too. system simply copy `InternalHigh` from `OVERLAPPED` to *`*lpNumberOfBytes`*. so in pseudo code :

```
if (lpNumberOfBytes) *lpNumberOfBytes = (ULONG)lpOverlapped->InternalHigh;
```

obvivous correct value in *`*lpNumberOfBytes`* will be only if I/O already completed with success. so and can use it only in this case. system doesn't remember value of  *`lpNumberOfBytes`* - because this it must be valid only during `[Write|Read]File` call but not during I/O active (which can be longer in case asynchronous I/O)

`GetOverlappedResult` we can call if I/O request complete synchronous with success (in case `ReadFile` or `WriteFile`, if thay return `TRUE`) of if pending returned. this api can not be called only in case I/O request just fail (`ReadFile` or `WriteFile` return `FALSE` and `GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING`)

so the best always pass not 0 *lpNumberOfBytes* to api and use it, if api complete just with success. otherwise use `GetOverlappedResult` or if say you use `BindIoCompletionCallback` - you direct got `dwNumberOfBytesTransfered` in callback.

so in conceptually can use next code:

```
inline ULONG BOOL_TO_ERROR(BOOL f)
{
    return f ? NOERROR : GetLastError();
}

HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(*, FILE_GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, 0, 
    OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, 0);

if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    UCHAR buf[0x200];
    OVERLAPPED ov = {};
    ULONG NumberOfBytesRead;

    ULONG dwError = BOOL_TO_ERROR(ReadFile(hFile, buf, sizeof(buf), &NumberOfBytesRead, &ov));

    switch (dwError)
    {
    case ERROR_IO_PENDING:
        dwError = BOOL_TO_ERROR(GetOverlappedResult(hFile, &ov, &NumberOfBytesRead, TRUE));
        if (dwError != NOERROR) goto __default;
        [[fallthrough]];

    case NOERROR:
        DbgPrint("NumberOfBytesRead=%x\n", NumberOfBytesRead);
        // use GetOverlappedResult(hFile, &ov, &NumberOfBytesRead, TRUE) here also possible
        break;
__default:
    default:
    DbgPrint("dwError = %u\n", dwError);
    }

    CloseHandle(hFile);
}
```

Comment: @eryksun - yes, of course `Offset` and `OffsetHigh` must be explicitly set, if file support file position (filesystem). for say pipes offset irrelevant. but i not focused on that. the question was about else

Comment: Is NumberOfBytesRead valid if GetOverlappedResult returns FALSE.  Say a partial read before error occurred or value undefined?

Comment: @user3161924 - if GetOverlappedResult returns FALSE - NumberOfBytesRead not valid. the *NumberOfBytes* (readed/written) valid only after operation complete with success. if io fail - *NumberOfBytes* is not valid and actual vallue is 0

Comment: "*must not*  point to a location ..." is easily misleading wording I think. Better, IMO, would be 'does not have to point to a location...". Must not gives the impression that it cannot/should not 'point to a location..."

Comment: @nyholku - yes, agree. i simply bad know english