# Async file IO doesn't return ERROR_IO_PENDING

Tags: c++, windows, timer

I'm trying to make an asynchronous IO operation work. However, both the WriteFile and ReadFile functions do not work; WriteFile doesn't print out `prompt1` and ReadFile doesn't return `chBuffer[200]` so consequently the switch statement returns the default output "option not valid!". Moreover the functions fail to return `ERROR_IO_PENDING`.

Here is my code for more information:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Timer {
public:
    Timer() = default;
    ~Timer() {};

    BOOL ioOperations() {
        if (!WriteFile(hFile, prompt1, bytesPrompt1, NULL, &ov1)) {
            return GetLastError(); // Minor check to see if WriteFile returns ERROR_IO_PENDING.
        }
        
        if (!ReadFile(hFile, chBuffer, dwRead, NULL, &ov2)) {
            return chBuffer[200];
            // return GetLastError(); // Minor check to see if ReadFile returns ERROR_IO_PENDING.
        }   
    }

    BOOL waitOperation() {
        BOOL waitFunc = WaitForSingleObject(hFile, dwTimeOut);
        if (waitFunc == WAIT_FAILED) {
            std::cout << "****WaitForSingleObject: An error was encountered****" << std::endl;
            return GetLastError();
        }
        else {
            return waitFunc == WAIT_OBJECT_0;
        }
    }

    BOOL funcCloseHandle() {
        BOOL closeFile = CloseHandle(hFile);
        if (closeFile == 0) {
            std::cout << "****CloseHandle: An error was encountered****" << std::endl;
            return GetLastError();
        }
        else {
            return closeFile;
        }
    }

public:
    CHAR chBuffer[201]{};

protected:
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileA(
        "MainFile.txt",
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
        NULL
    );

private:
    LPCSTR prompt1{ "Option: " };

    DWORD dwRead{ 200 };
    DWORD bytesPrompt1{ sizeof(prompt1) };
    DWORD dwTimeOut{ 5'000 };

    OVERLAPPED ov1{ 0, 0, 0, 0, CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, TEXT("OverlappedOne")) };
    OVERLAPPED ov2{ 0, 0, 0, 0, CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, TEXT("OverlappedTwo")) };
};

int main() {
    Timer tm{};

    // std::cout << "sizeof class Timer: " << sizeof(Timer) << std::endl;

    do {
        tm.ioOperations();

        switch (tm.chBuffer[0]) {
        case '1': std::cout << "option 1" << std::endl;
            break;
        case '2': std::cout << "option 2" << std::endl;
            break;
        case '3': std::cout << "exit" << std::endl;
            break;
        default: std::cout << "option not valid!" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    } while (tm.waitOperation());

    tm.funcCloseHandle();

    return 0;
}
```

I tried changing multiple things such as the `CreateFile`'s file name, the `OVERLAPPED` structures' values, as well as the parameters of the `WriteFile` and `ReadFile` functions, however nothing works except `WaitForSingleObject`.

As a sidenote even though I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56982341/readfile-and-writefile-with-overlapped-io-result-if-not-error-io-pending) question, the problems still remain.

Can someone please tell me how to make these async functions work together?